# Seeing if a file exists with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a file that I need to see if it exists when I run a stub, but the location of this file is uncertain at time of testing.  I've got some pseducode for how I think it may work, but I think something is still incorrect.  Basically, the actual code runs Dir.glob("/opt/test-*/bin/progname").exists? to see if there is a file there.  Do I need to break this into more than 1 line?

`Dir.stubs(:glob).with("/opt/test-*/bin/progname").exists?returns(true)`

Answer (score 1):

If you stub out `Dir.glob` then you won't be testing that you're calling it properly. Instead you can actually write a file to a test location in the example set up:

```
before(:each) do 
  FileUtils.cp source, destination
end
```

and clean it up after:

```
after(:each) do
  FileUtils.rm destination
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct variation for you are trying to fo is:
    Dir.stubs(:glob).with("/opt/test-*/bin/progname").and_return(double("glob", :'exists?' => true)

You can use [`FakeFS`](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) gem instead to simulate the file system:

```
FakeFS.activate!

File.open('/opt/test-this/bin/progname', 'w') { |f| f.write('something') }
```